# How to create new GMimeMessage from string?

Tags: c++, mime

In my project i use libgmime for MIME types. I'm trying to create new **GMimeMessage** using std::string as a body.
According to docs it can be done using **GMimeStream** and **GMimeDataWrapper** for preparing data, and then creating **GMimePart** from this data to be set as MIME part of new message.
The code:

```
std::string body = "some test data";
GMimeMessage* message = g_mime_message_new(FALSE);
//set header
g_mime_object_set_header((GMimeObject *) message, name.c_str()), value.c_str();
//create stream and write data into it.
GMimeStream* stream;
g_mime_stream_construct(stream, 0, body.length());
g_mime_stream_write_string(stream, body.c_str());
GMimeDataWrapper* wrapper = g_mime_data_wrapper_new_with_stream(stream,  GMIME_CONTENT_ENCODING_DEFAULT);
//create GMimePart to be set as mime part of GMimeMessage
GMimePart* mime_part = g_mime_part_new();
g_mime_part_set_content_object(mime_part, wrapper);

g_mime_message_set_mime_part(message, (GMimeObject *) mime_part);
```

When i try to create message in this way, i get segfault here:

```
g_mime_stream_write_string(stream, body.c_str());
```

Maybe i'm using wrong method of message creation...
What's the right way it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad initialization `GMimeStream *stream`. Need:

```
GMimeStream *stream;

/* initialize GMime */
g_mime_init (0);

/* create a stream around stdout */
stream = g_mime_stream_mem_new_with_buffer(body_part.c_str(), body_part.length());
```

See doc: http://spruce.sourceforge.net/gmime/tutorial/x49.html
And sample: http://fossies.org/linux/gmime/examples/basic-example.c